# how to use CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE and CPACK_NSIS_FINISH_TITLE?

Tags: windows, cmake, nsis, cpack

Using CPack and NSIS to package my application.  Everything works well, with the exception of the following:  I cannot figure out how to use `CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE` and `CPACK_NSIS_FINISH_TITLE`.

All of my CPack options/customizations are in 1 place, just prior to calling `INCLUDE (CPack)`.  Here are examples of what I've tried:

```
SET ( CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE          "afasfasf asfafasf test!!!" )
SET ( CPACK_NSIS_FINISH_TITLE           "blah blah blah testing" )
```

I've also tried the "3LINES" versions like this:

```
SET ( CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE_3LINES   "This is the title line.\nMore text.\nThird line." )
SET ( CPACK_NSIS_FINISH_TITLE_3LINES    "afaf afafaf afasfaf affaf test test test afafasf afasfasf" )
```

While the installer is created without error, I don't see any of this text appearing anywhere on the welcome screen, the finish screen, or any other screen.

This is the version of cmake/cpack I'm using:

```
C:\src\Project\build64>"\Program Files\CMake\bin\cpack.exe" --version
cpack version 3.16.0-rc3
```

The end of the console output it generates seems to indicate there were no problems:

```
...
  CPack: Create package using NSIS
  CPack: Install projects
  CPack: - Install project: Project [Debug]
  CPack: Create package
  CPack: - package: C:/src/Project/build64/project_v1.0.1.exe generated.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Debug\PACKAGE\PACKAGE.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Debug\PACKAGE\PACKAGE.tlog\PACKAGE.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\src\Project\build64\PACKAGE.vcxproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question and its answer are confusing because you can't set CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE_3LINES to a string. Instead you should turn it on:

```
set(CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE_3LINES   ON)
```

and now you can set CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE to 3 lines (normally you can only have 2 lines):

```
set(CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE   "This is the title line.\\\\nMore Text.\\\\nThird line.")
```

Don't forget the 4 slashes to escape the pyramid of tools! ;-)

Comment: Back when I asked it several years ago, it wasn't obvious that this was a ON/OFF setting.  There were next to no docs and examples showing how it worked.  Thanks for setting the record straight.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation ([3.16.4](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/cpack_gen/nsis.html) and [3.17.0-rc1](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/cpack_gen/nsis.html)) the variables you mention (`CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE, CPACK_NSIS_FINISH_TITLE, CPACK_NSIS_WELCOME_TITLE_3LINES, CPACK_NSIS_FINISH_TITLE_3LINES`) have been introduced only recently in `CMake 3.17.0-rc1`. As you are using `CMake` version 3.16.0-rc3 you need to upgrade.